# News and weather app/widget crashes on startup

Tags: 2.2-froyo, nexus-one, news-and-weather

Over the past couple of days, the news and weather app won't start for me.  I get an error message and I'm asked to force close or report the issue whenever I try to add the widget to a home screen or launch the app from the app tray.  Does anyone know what's causing the issue, and if so, how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you updated it to the latest version?

Comment: what is the latest version. I searched the store, but could not find it on there. my stock G2 has "Version 1.2.02-RC2(PROD)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try clearing the cache and/or clearing app data.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm.  I guess it just got in a weird states during my vacation travels.

Comment: There's always a few things that I try with a truculent app: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/91/app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it