# How do I clear the settings of a built in app in Cyanogenmod 9 (ICS)?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod

I just updated my phone (Galaxy S2) to the latest stable version of Cyanogen, and I can't set any alarms in the default clock app.  When I try to go to the screen to set the alarms, the app just crashes.  [Past experience](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4133/news-and-weather-app-widget-crashes-on-startup) tells me the solution is the clear the app data/cache, but the problem is that the app doesn't show up in the apps list in the settings.

How am I supposed to clear these settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI is a little different than before, and instead of the tabs all fitting on the screen, you have to scroll to the left or right to see some of them instead.  The "All" tab in the apps menu is off to the right of the screen.  Simply pull the tabs left, and the "All" tab will be shown.  From there, it's the same as always for clearing app data.